# React re-render vs function re-evaluation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone validate if my assumptions after docs and tutorials reading are correct? First of all I would like to introduce some terminology:

`reevaluation` is when react updates its VirtualDOM and happens when

- component is not memoized and parent component re-evaluates (not necessary props must change)
- component is memoized and its props/state changes
- component's state changes

So `rerender` is when react updates DOM and happens when:

- re-evaluated virtual DOM node is different than DOM node

Could you confirm am I right?

Comment: your thinking seems right, but the majority of people would call react `render` to be calling your components (it's inaccurate, but its the popular usage of the word) and DOM updates you can say repaint or something. so you could call render many times without actually updating the dom ever

Comment: your explanation is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Re-Evaluating Components != Re-Rendering DOM**

- Components get re-evaluated whenever props, state, or context changes
- DOM re-render when there is difference between evaluations